# When cannot a local module (.ts file) be found when imported?

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, importerror

I am writing my first node.js program (I wrote over the years some JS/TS frontend code, as well as Go, Python), and after some first basic tests I started to modularize my code (to group it in logical chunks).

I have an exported `getConfig()` function in `D:\W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src\config.ts` and would like to use it in my `D:\W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src\main.ts` one:

```
import { getConfig } from "./config"

getConfig()
```

I get the error

```
PS D:\W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src> ts-node-esm .\main.ts
C:\Users\W\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module 'D:\W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src\config' imported from D:\W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src\main.ts
```

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) explains how the actual import is done, and this mirrors my setup:

> For example, an import statement like `import { b } from "./moduleB"`
> in `/root/src/moduleA.ts` would result in attempting the following
> locations for locating `"./moduleB"`:
>
> `/root/src/moduleB.ts`
> (...)

In that case why do I get the `Cannot find module ...` error when the `.ts` file is present where expected?

---

For reference, my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2022",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "lib": [
        "es2015"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./src/*.ts",
        "./src/**/*.ts",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" the issue by adding `.js` to the imported file (`import { getConfig } from "./config.js"`) but I have no idea why it works that way.

I can wildly guess that, ultimately, the file that is processed by JS is a `.js` file generated from the `.ts` one but it seems really weird to import it that way (but it works).

EDIT: this is actually [documented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html):

> (...) relative import paths need to use extensions. As a result, it will have to be rewritten to use the extension of the output of `foo.ts` - so `bar.ts` will instead have to import from `./foo.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you export the getConfig() function in the config.ts file?

First you should  `export function getConfig() { ... }`
and then you can `import { getConfig } from "./config"`

Comment: Yes, it is exported but the problem is not there: it's the file to import that cannot be found, not the function.